# Multiple filter value webpart connection problem

Tags: web-part, filter, xslt-list-view-web-part

We currently try to connect a custom webpart with a list view webpart.
The aim is to send multiple filter values to the list view.
The problem we have is that the list view does only use the FIRST value.
Its really strange because the list expects a array of strings.

```
public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> ParameterValues
{
   get
   {
   return new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(new string[]{"Name1", "Name2"});
   }
}
```

Is this not supported in SharePoint 2013?
This works fine for SharePoint 2010.

Any workarounds,other solutions or approaches?

Thanks in advance!